# Check if string character matches array value

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little trouble with a small challenge. I'm trying to check to see if a string's character is found in an array and if so, stop the loop, log the value, and start over with a new string character. Can anyone elp

```
function LetterChanges(str) {    
    var alphabet =   ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    // code goes here
    var myString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i <= myString.length; i++) {
        for(var o = 0; o < 25; o++){
            var getChar = myString += str.charAt(i)
            if (getChar == alphabet[o]){
                alert(getChar);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(getChar);          
}

// keep this function call here
LetterChanges("Test");`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    // code goes here
    var regex=/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]/;

    // simply you can give as below
    regex = /[a-z]/;

    //if you want to match Cap A-Z too make the regex to ignore case as below
    // regex = /[a-z]/i; 

    var myString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var char = str[i];
        if (regex.test(char)) {
            myString += char;
            console.log(myString)
        }
    }
    console.log(myString);
}

// keep this function call here
LetterChanges("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you're just starting out, take a look at how to use `debugger` and breakpoints. They'll help you figure out what your code is doing.
- Try looping over `alphabet.length` instead of `25`
- Creating `var getChar` seems unnecessary. Try just doing `if(str.chartAt(i) == alphabet[o])`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {    
    var alphabet =   ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    
   
    for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        for(var o = 0; o < 25; o++){
              
            if (str.charAt(i) == alphabet[o]){
                alert(getChar);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(getChar);          
}

// keep this function call here
LetterChanges("Test"); </script>
```

note that , letter 'T' will not match in array. so only 'e' , 's' , 't' will be alert.